Split polygon based on what's visible on the screen
I have two datasets - a large polygon that contains all wards boundaries, and a gps coordinates of places visited, that fall within a city's boundaries as well as slightly outside. I'd like to save a subset of the ward polygon in such a way that not only all my gps coordinates would fall into this polygon, but that the polygon is "square/rectangular" shape.
Essentially, I would like to do the following:
a) Zoom to layer the gps coordinates, to identify the area I would like to save, and
b) Save the large polygon but only what is "visible" on the screen (see below)
Splitting features wouldn't work as I would have to zoom out to draw the line without actually knowing whether I would split the feature too "low" or too "high" without multiple trial and error.


What tool are you planning on using?

Hi Ian, I'm using QGIS version 2.18.23

well I would move to the century of the fruit bat and version 3.x

You can use the geoprocessing tool Extract/Clip by Extent. Zoom how you wish, then click the "set to current map canvas extent" button. Make sure to opt to clip the features.


PS: QGIS 2.18 is an archaeological artifact, I don't know if this tool existed in this era.

Thanks JGH - I'm currently downloading an updated version, I also noticed that the tool doesn't exist in the version I have.
